# Select Distinct in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I return the unique records for `AccountDescription`? I am aware of how to use `distinct` but I am not sure how to apply it in this case.

```
    SELECT
      Contacts.FirstName,
      Contacts.LastName,
      Account.AccountType,
      Account.AccountDescription
    FROM Contacts
    INNER JOIN Account
      ON Contacts.UserID = Account.AccountID
    WHERE UserAccountType LIKE '%TEST%'
    AND AccountType = 'trial'
```

I basically need to grab all the unique `AccountDescription` as there are many contacts that have the same `AccountDescription`.

What I currently have returning :

```
AccountType : Trial , AccountDescription : test1
AccountType : Trial , AccountDescription : test2
AccountType : Trial , AccountDescription : test1
```

I need to grab the unique `AccountDescription`

Comment: No criticism intended, but I am honestly curious of what sense you are _"aware of how to use distinct"_ since this is pretty much the most basic and first use people become acquainted with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Contacts.FirstName, Contacts.LastName,
Account.AccountType, Account.AccountDescription
FROM Contacts INNER JOIN Account ON Contacts.UserID = Account.AccountID
WHERE UserAccountType LIKE '%TEST%' AND AccountType = 'trial'
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself by using `GROUP BY AccountDescription;`

Comment: Note that if you group by AccountDescription, you're basically throwing away all the data in the other three fields, and generally have no reason for them; the values you'll get in them are _officially_ not predictable... especially if AccountDescription is not even unique in it's own table.